# How to prevent spam searches

Tags: spam-prevention

My application http://www.tyro.in has search facility when ever user searches, that query will appear in recent searches area. My search form uses GET method. I think spammers search spam words and that spam words are directly posted on my site. I don't want to change my form method from GET to POST. Please suggest any way to identify and prevent the spam queries.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add a hidden input field to your search form, and also to the user's session. When the form is posted, match the input field value to the session. A spam search will be missing this value, since he won't have a session.

```
$hiddenvalue= md5(rand(0,1000));

//only fill session if we're not coming from a search action
if(count($_GET) == 0) {
    $_SESSION["hidden"]= $hiddenvalue;
}


<input type="hidden" name="secret" value="$hiddenvalue">
```

Then after the GET:

```
if($_GET["secret"] == $_SESSION["hidden"]) {
    //continue search
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter searches that do not fit your content. This way, typos (and exotic searches that always happen) will not showon under "recent searches" as well.